# How to add mozilla dependency in updated android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, rhino

```
implementation 'org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.13'.
```

its giving syntax error in updated version

Am trying to import mozilla library in java.anyone can please guide me regarding this error.i want to use built in functions like `setOptimizationLevel()` and enter() etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead:

```
implementation "com.faendir.rhino:rhino-android:1.6.0"
```

It handles optimization settings and other compatibility issues for you.
Check out this android example project for reference https://github.com/F43nd1r/rhino-android-example.

Comment: THis project hasn't had an update in over 4 years.  Nobody should use this for anything other than *possibly* a learning tool for the example.  It's using a version of Rhino with no security updates for most of a decade.